# How to convert from a ParameterMap of HttpServletRequest to a bean in Java

Tags: java, servlets, converters, javabeans, data-conversion

I have a string of parameters in URL and I want to convert this string into a bean object.
For example, I have the URL `www.domain.com/book?authorFirstName=Dostoevsky` and I want to get a bean, a capsule for criterias:

```
public class BookCriterias {
    ...
    public String getAuthorFirstName() {...}
    public void setAuthorFirstName(String fName) {...}
    public String getAuthorLastName() {...}
    public void setAuthorLastName(String lName) {...}
    public String getGenre() {...}
    public void setGenre(String genre) {...}
}
```

Does some ready-to-use library exist for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on your libraries but a standard `javax.servlet.ServletRequest` class has a [`Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap--) method:

> Returns:
>
> an immutable java.util.Map containing parameter names as keys and parameter values as map values. The keys in the parameter map are of type String. The values in the parameter map are of type String array.

After that it's a simple Map to Bean scenario which can be accomplished with most bean mapping tools like [Orika Mapper](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika) or [Commons BeanUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/). You can try to use the latter with:

```
BookCriterias bc = new BookCriterias();
BeanUtils.populate(bc, request.getParamterMap());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like this:

```
String authorFirstName = request.getParameter("authorFirstName");
BookCriterias bc = new BookCriterias();
if(authorFirstName!=null && authorFirstName!=""){
   bc.setAuthorFirstName(authorFirstName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jersey or Dropwizard, you can have your own implementation of `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter` where you can get hold of URIInfo Object from `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext` and convert QueryParameters to whatever object you want and set it back into `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext`.

By this way, you can get criteria as a bean in your Resource class.